# Apache mod_wsgi error

Tags: django, apache

I am trying to deploy a Django application to apache using mod_wsgi module with the following at the end of my `/etc/apache/apache2.conf` file

```
ServerName localhost

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/d_sehgal/Desktop/Bulk-Mailing-Solution/Bulk-Mailing-Solution/MailingSolution/MailingSolution
WSGIPythonHome /usr/bin/python3

<Directory  /home/d_sehgal/Desktop/Bulk-Mailing-Solution/Bulk-Mailing-Solution/MailingSolution/MailingSolution/>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess www.example.com python-home=/usr/bin/python3 python-path=/home/d_sehgal/Desktop/Bulk-Mailing-Solution/Bulk-Mailing-Solution/MailingSolution
WSGIProcessGroup www.example.com
```

Apache version info:

```
root@divij-VirtualBox:/home/d_sehgal# apache2ctl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2016-07-14T12:32:26
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:52
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

I have checked various answers and links but I cannot figure out what leads to this error.

P.S. Newbie here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Problem Solved. Had to do with the fact that Order and Allow directives have been replaced by Require directive in Apache 2.4

Comment: Your ``python-home`` option is set wrong. It should not be the path to a Python executable. Make sure you read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html